# Replicate Azure VM's to use with load balancer

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, replication

I want to have multiple VM's for my webtier and a load balancer configured in Azure. Currently I have 1 VM and load balancer working, I can easily create a 2nd VM and get it to work with the load balancer, but then I'd have to fully re-configure the 2nd VM even though it is identical to the first VM.

How can I easily copy/replicate my main VM and create a 2nd or 3rd VM that is identical so I can provide a multi-VM setup? It's not just about the VM technical configuration, but mostly about the software installed and IIS config for instance.

I'm using Azure's new Resource Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning an Azure VM is done by using normal operations for preparing a machine for imaging.

Windows machines will need to be [sysprepped](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721940(v=ws.10).aspx) and then [captured](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-classic-capture-image/).
There are ways to do this either through the GUI or through Powershell / CLI.
But whatever method you choose, you will need access to the VM in question.

Linux machines will need to be prepared by the azure linux agent, [waagent.](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-agent-user-guide/)
The linux agent will deprovision your machine, and prepare it for capturing.
`sudo waagent -deprovision+user`
You can then deallocate the resources, and generalize + capture the machine.

[From the azure documentation for capturing Linux VM's](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-linux-capture-image/):

> Make sure you are in Resource Manager mode:
>
> `azure config mode arm`
>
> Stop the VM which you already deprovisioned by using the following
>   command:
>
> `azure vm deallocate -g <your-resource-group-name> -n <your-virtual-machine-name>`
>
> Generalize the VM with the following command:
>
> `azure vm generalize –g <your-resource-group-name> -n <your-virtual-machine-name>`
>
> Now capture the image and a local file template with the following
>   command:
>
> `azure vm capture <your-resource-group-name> <your-virtual-machine-name> <your-vhd-name-prefix> -t <your-template-file-name.json>`
>
> This command creates a generalized OS image, using the VHD name prefix
>   you specify for the VM disks. The image VHD files get created by
>   default in the same storage account that the original VM used. The -t
>   option creates a local JSON file template you can use to create a new
>   VM from the image.